# ERREUR JAVA : Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I tried to install javafx (javafx-sdk-11.0.2) on java eclipse (2020-12), following all the steps you need to do to run the main code, without errorof,of the javafx project: add user library in the class path, and the VM (--module-path "C: \ javafx \ javafx-sdk-11.0.2 \ lib" --add-modules = javafx.controls, javafx.fxml) but still the error remains display.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS90V.png)

[images of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvuXl.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Don't add screenshots of code and errors.

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" an occurrence of this problem that came up for me when trying to run the example program from the Gluon [Getting Started section for modular Eclipse projects](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse) by editing the *Run Configurations*.

Under the *Dependencies* tab, add the folder that holds the JavaFX jar files (the `/lib` subfolder of the jdk). If you inspect the generated command line, it should now include that folder in the **-p** option.

Once this was done, the tutorial program ran without a problem.

This begs the question why this step is even necessary, though. Eclipse is "smart enough" to automatically add other modules to the dependencies. Why not the JavaFX library if it has been specified in the Build Path configuration? Why no mention of the additional run configuration dependencies step in the Gluon tutorial?

I have pending questions on this asked at eclipse.org and gluon.